# Pagination Not Working on `WP_Query` Archive Page

Tags: pagination, archives, paginate-links

I have an archive page that pulls two different custom post types into an archive using `WP_Query()`. Because there is a home page to the site which shows 9 of the custom post type posts, I offset the archive page by 9 posts.

The code for this is:

```
$homePageArticles = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 18,
        'offset' => 9,
        'post_type'=> array('articles', 'featured')
    ));

    while(  $homePageArticles->have_posts()){
            $homePageArticles->the_post(); ?>

            // HTML

<?php } ?>
```

However on this archive page the `<?php echo paginate_links();?>` function to show the pagination pages doesn't work.

I can click through the numbers or use the next and previous arrows, but it just shows the same posts on each page.

The pagination code I'm using is:

```
<p>
    <?php echo paginate_links(array(
        'prev_text' => 'NEWER',
        'next_text' => 'OLDER',
        'mid_size' => 0
    ));?>
</p>
```

On normal custom archive pages on the site (which don't use `WP_Query();`) the pagination works fine.

Any help or assistance would be amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that with a custom `WP_Query` class instance like the `$homePageArticles` in your case, you should pass the `max_num_pages` property of the class instance to [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/):

```php
paginate_links( array(
    'total' => $homePageArticles->max_num_pages,
) )
```

However, that alone will not work with custom offset which [breaks the pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination), hence for example you got this issue:

> it just shows the same posts on each page

But it can be fixed and it's quite easy:

1. Calculate the offset based on the current page number and pass the offset to `WP_Query`:

   ```php
   // Current page number.
   $paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

   $per_page     = 18; // posts per page
   $offset_start = 9;  // initial offset
   $offset       = $paged ? ( $paged - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset_start : $offset_start;

   $homePageArticles = new WP_Query( array(
       'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
       'offset'         => $offset,
       'post_type'      => 'articles',
       // No need to set 'paged'.
   ) );
   ```
2. Recalculate the `max_num_pages` property and pass it to `paginate_links()`:

   ```php
   $homePageArticles->found_posts   = max( 0, $homePageArticles->found_posts - $offset_start )
   $homePageArticles->max_num_pages = ceil( $homePageArticles->found_posts / $per_page );

   while ( $homePageArticles->have_posts() ) ...

   echo paginate_links( array(
       'current' => $paged,
       'total'   => $homePageArticles->max_num_pages,
       ...
   ) );
   ```

### *But then,* if you're making the custom WP query in an archive template, e.g. `archive-articles.php` ([`archive-<post type>`.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types))

Then you should just forget that custom WP query.

And instead, use the [`pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to filter the main WP query args (to set the custom offset), then use the [`found_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/found_posts/) to make sure we have the correct `max_num_pages` value, then just loop through the posts in the main query.

1. In the theme functions file:

   ```php
   function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
       if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() &&
           is_post_type_archive( 'articles' )
       ) {
           $query->set( 'offset_start', 9 );
           $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 18 );
       }

       if ( $offset = $query->get( 'offset_start' ) ) {
           $per_page = absint( $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) );
           $per_page = $per_page ? $per_page : max( 1, get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) );

           $paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
           $query->set( 'offset', ( $paged - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset );
       }
   }
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );

   function my_found_posts( $found_posts, $query ) {
       if ( $offset = $query->get( 'offset_start' ) ) {
           $found_posts = max( 0, $found_posts - $offset );
       }

       return $found_posts;
   }
   add_filter( 'found_posts', 'my_found_posts', 10, 2 );
   ```
2. Then in your archive template:

   ```php
   // No need for the "new WP_Query()".
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       ... your code.
   endwhile;

   // No need to set 'current' or 'total'.
   echo paginate_links( array(
       'prev_text' => 'NEWER',
       'next_text' => 'OLDER',
       ...
   ) );
   ```

And actually, with the custom functions in #1 above, you could simply use the *custom `offset_start` arg* with any `WP_Query` instances:

```php
// Current page number.
$paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

$homePageArticles = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 18,
    'offset_start'   => 9, // <- set this
    'post_type'      => 'articles',
    // No need to set 'paged' or 'offset'.
) );

while ( $homePageArticles->have_posts() ) ...

echo paginate_links( array(
    'current' => $paged,
    'total'   => $homePageArticles->max_num_pages,
    ...
) );
```

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ this doesn't work. I either get a white screen or no pagination.

Comment: Hi @TheChewy, I have revised the answer. That should work, but please check it out and let me know.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ that does work now. It's really appreciated. One other good thing about this is it finally made me start learning about actions and filters, it's early days obviously, but a basic grasp of the concept of Hooks seems to be sinking in.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that and sorry, I should've asked *what/which* archive that you're referring to in the first place.. but I simply ended up assuming it's a static Page that lists your posts using a custom Page Template.. maybe because of the "custom archive pages" in the question.. :p Anyway, good luck! :)

Comment: Hi @TheChewy. I don't know why did you unaccept my answer, but hopefully the revised one is more helpful.

Comment: I found the problem. I got it to work using the 2nd answer (using all 3 blocks of code), but when the number of posts on the archive page template is less than 3 it creates an extra pagination link that breaks. I added some dummy posts & when I do a `posts per page` of 3 or more it seems to work all OK. Also I only unmarked it as correct because I thought I had to do this to comment (like you do on the Wordpress.org site, apologies for that). Also do you have a paypay/patreon account? If so DM me the address and I'd be happy to ping some bucks for all your help.

Comment: Sorry about that "posts per page" issue. I have fixed it, check the revision to see the changes. And I'd be more than happy if you can re-accept my answer, and if I understood you properly, no, you don't need to unaccept an answer in order to comment on the answer - as long as you've got [50 or more reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), then you can comment on answers/questions.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. That's been marked as correct again.

Comment: The best solution for me. saved a lot of time. thank you @SallyCJ